# How do I update a collection on hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
  Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  Set<B>  children;
}

class B {
  Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  A parent;
}
```

there's data in the database, say a1 that has {b1, b2, b3} as children.
when i try to update a1's set of children to {b4, b5} i end up having b1..b5 in the database.
in my code, i take the precaution of calling `clear()` on the children set, but it does not affect the database.

should i iterate and call `session.delete(child)` on each child of A's ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Java EE 6 (and Hibernate 3.5), you should use [@OneToMany(...,orphanRemoval=true)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval%28%29)

Prior to Java EE 6/Hibernate 3.5, you can use `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`, which was deprecated in 3.5 in favor of the addition of orphanRemoval to the JPA.

Comment: I'm using hibernate 3.6.4 and DELETE_ORPHAN appears as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Javadocs say it's deprecated in favor of Deprecated. use @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true) or @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true). I'm going to update the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Cascade.All on the child items. The basic problem is that even though you are clearing the set on the parent object, the child objects will save themselves as having a1 as a parent. Meaning that you need to clear BOTH sides of the relationship. There are two routes:

1. Remove the cascade.all on the child items and let the parent object manage the entire relationship.
2. Manually handle the relationships yourself by clearing the parent element on the child ones, or full-on deleting them from the session. In choosing this route, you are going to need to be VERY explicit about what happens to each element in the set.

Comment: tried removing the cascade from the children side, still same effect. previous child members don't get deleted. any idea why?

Comment: Did you try doing a clear() after removing the cascade from one side? If that doesn't work, your best bet is to try route 2 - hibernate is very strict about how it will let you manage hasmany relationships.